# How do I pass a constant string vector to a function for string matching?

Tags: c++, string, function, vector, find

Edit 2: Adding `#include <algorithm>` fixed the code.

I am trying to match strings, but I am getting errors that indicate that I am not using the proper data type for the `std::find` function.  For my purposes, the vector doesn't necessarily have to be constant.

```
bool string_in_vector(const std::string &str,std::vector<std::string> &arr)
{
 return std::find(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),str) != std::end(arr);
}
```

I have also tried this for constant vector types:

```
bool string_in_vector(const std::string &str,const std::vector<std::string> &arr)
{
 return std::find(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),str) != std::end(arr);
}
```

and

```
bool string_in_vector(const std::string &str,std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator arr)
{
 return std::find(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),str) != std::end(arr);
}
```

But I haven't had any luck with getting the right data types.  An error is thrown for `std::find` for the first and second functions above, and an error is thrown for `std::begin` when I follow `<std::string>` with `::const_iterator` (the third function).  All of these errors are "no matching function".

What should be done to fix this issue?

Edit (error messages):
    ||=== Build: Debug in thtag (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

```
/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp||In function ‘bool string_in_vector(const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|22|error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, const string&)’|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|22|note: candidate is:|

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h|369|note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, const _CharT2&)|

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h|369|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|22|note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ is not derived from ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>’|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp||In function ‘void read_pdf(const char*)’:|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|74|warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|79|warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]|

 /home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp||In function ‘bool string_in_vector(const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:|

/home/user/workspace/thtag/main.cpp|23|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46fc93ac99251753). Can you add the exact error message + the compiler you are using?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the first and second versions of the function. I am able to use them with g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: The error I got is above.  I used the GNU GCC compiler.  Also, I use the `-std=c++0x` compiler setting.

Comment: std::begin() and std::end() have been added in C++11. Use `arr.begin()` a and `arr.end()` instead for the first and second versions.

Comment: I'm still having issues with `std::find`, though.

Comment: Did you not `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Adding `#include <algorithm>` fixed the code.  Thanks.